# Count negative values in a list of integers using Python?

Tags: python

I am having problems with [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p210362) CodingBat question:

> Given a list of integers, return the count of the negative values.

```
count_negative([-1, -2, -3]) → 3
count_negative([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]) → 0
count_negative([-5, -3, 4]) → 2
```

Why doesn't this code run correctly?

```
def count_negative(list):
  for value in list:
      total = 0
      total += value
      return total
```

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `total` back to zero after every loop. Put it outside the loop:

Also, the function will break after the first loop, because after a function returns something it breaks. Also put `return total` outside of the loop:

```
total = 0
for value in list:
    total += value
return total
```

I don't see how this will determine whether a number is a negative or not. You can use an if-statement inside of your loop.

```
if value < 0:
    total += 1
```

Or you can just use a list comprehension:

```
sum(1 for i in lst if i < 0)
```

---

By the way, never name something `list`. It overrides the built-in. I'm rather surprised your question did it.

Comment: YEAH! using 'list' really bothers me. but its a quiz-ish question so i can't change it

Answer (score 2):

Without loops and conditions:

```
>>> lst = [1, -2, 3, -1, 2]
>>> neg = str(lst).count('-')
>>> neg
2
```

Comment: Fine, but it works JUST for integers. Scientific notation would mess it..a good solution is simple len(np.where(np.array(lst])<0)[0])

Comment: @Oalvinegro i don't see any problem with floats: print(str([1.01, -2.1, 3.1, -1.1, 2.2]).count('-')) you get also 2

Comment: For instance, you have print(str([1.01, 1.23e-05]).count('-')),  it gives you the wrong count

Comment: yes you  are right but in support of my approach, you can use such crutches str(['%f'%i for i in [1e-2, -1e-2]]).count('-') and you get 1

Comment: Ok, it is a solution but imho you are overly complicating a simple stuff...On top of that, it uses a loop for an answer that states "Without loops". Perhaps you should edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` you can have a single-line solution:

`len(np.where(np.array(lst)<0)[0])`

Answer (score -2):

Turn it into a `pd.DataFrame` then use `df[df>0].count()/len(df)`

Comment: This is a terrible solution to the problem. You don't want to convert a simple list into a more complex data structure, when using the builtin `sum` function is the simplest solution and the fastest